# parsing json to allow nil or default value for dictionary

Tags: arrays, json, swift, dictionary

I think I know what my problem is but I don't know how to fix it. I'm parsing json and I know that my variable "cooldown"  will be nil occasionally. How do I set the value to 0 when it returns nil? The issue arises when casting (maybe not the right term?) it to my talent class. I've bold the code that gives the error.

The error is "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value".

Ive tried using an If statement to check for cooldown = nil before performing the "let talent = ..." but that didn't work (or i didn't do it right).

```
if let talentsArray = dict[x]["talents"] as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {

                            for y in 0 ..< dict.count {
                                if let allHeroTalents = talentsArray["\(y)"]{
                                    for z in 0 ..< allHeroTalents.count {

                                        if let id = allHeroTalents[z]["id"], let name = allHeroTalents[z]["name"], let descritption = allHeroTalents[z]["description"], var cooldown = allHeroTalents[z]["cooldown"], let prerequisite = allHeroTalents[z]["prerequisite"], let icon = allHeroTalents[z]["icon"] {

                                            print("\(name) and \(cooldown)")

                                            let talent = Talent(id: id as! String, name: name as! String, description: description as! String, cooldown: cooldown as! Int, prerequisite: prerequisite as! String, icon: icon as! String)

                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
```

**let talent = Talent(id: id as! String, name: name as! String, description: description as! String, cooldown: cooldown as! Int, prerequisite: prerequisite as! String, icon: icon as! String)**

I know that I'm telling the code that cooldown will have a value because of the "cooldown: cooldown as! Int" but if I take out the ! the code gives me another error "value of optional type Int not unwrapped"

I know the json is working because the print i've added return correctly

Optional(Pressurized Glands) and Optional(6)

Optional(Survival Instincts) and nil

Optional(Regenerative Microbes) and Optional(12)

Optional(Envenomed Nest) and Optional(10)....

Below is the class for reference

```
class Talent {
private var _id: String!
private var _name: String!
private var _description: String!
private var _cooldown: Int!
private var _prerequisite: String!
private var _icon: String!


var id: String {
    if _id == nil {
        _id = ""
    }
    return _id
}
var name: String {
    if _name == nil {
        _name = ""
    }
    return _name
}
var description: String {
    if _description == nil {
        _description = ""
    }
    return _description
}
var cooldown: Int {
    if _cooldown == nil {
        _cooldown = 0
    }
    return _cooldown
}


var prerequisite: String {
    if _prerequisite == nil {
        _prerequisite = ""
    }
    return _prerequisite
}
var icon: String {
    if _icon == nil {
        _icon = ""
    }
    return _icon
}

init(id: String, name: String, description: String, cooldown: Int, prerequisite: String, icon: String) {
    self._id = id
    self._name = name
    self._description = description
    self._cooldown = cooldown
    self._prerequisite = prerequisite
    self._icon = icon

}
```

}

ADDED related JSON as requested (i think this is what you wanted)

```
func parseData(){
let urlString = "http://heroesjson.com/heroes.json"
let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
let url = NSURL(string: urlString)!
var stats = [Stats]()

session.dataTaskWithURL(url) { (data: NSData?, response:NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

    if let responseData = data {

        do {
            let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(responseData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments)

            if let dict = json as? [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>] {

                for x in 0 ..< dict.count {


                    if let id = dict[x]["id"], let attributeid = dict[x]["attributeid"], let name = dict[x]["name"], let title = dict[x]["title"], let description = dict[x]["description"], let role = dict[x]["role"], let type = dict[x]["type"], let gender = dict[x]["gender"], let franchise = dict[x]["franchise"], let difficulty = dict[x]["difficulty"], let icon = dict[x]["icon"] {

                        let hero = Hero(id: id as! String, attributeid: attributeid as! String, name: name as! String, title: title as! String, description: description as! String, role: role as! String, type: type as! String, gender: gender as! String, franchise: franchise as! String, difficulty: difficulty as! String, icon: icon as! String)

                        if let dataArray = dict[x]["ratings"] as? Dictionary<String, Int> {

                            if let damage = dataArray["damage"], let utility = dataArray["utility"], let survivability = dataArray["damage"], let complexity = dataArray["complexity"] {

                                let rating = Ratings(damage: damage as! Int, utility: utility as! Int, survivability: survivability as! Int, complexity: complexity as! Int)
                                hero.ratings = rating

                            }
                        }

                        if let statsArray = dict[x]["stats"] as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {

                            let val = statsArray["talents"]

                            if let dummy = statsArray[hero.id]{//error handleing for vikings


                                if let hp = statsArray[hero.id]!["hp"], let hpPerLevel = statsArray[hero.id]!["hpPerLevel"], let hpRegen = statsArray[hero.id]!["hpRegen"], let hpRegenPerLevel = statsArray[hero.id]!["hpRegenPerLevel"], let mana = statsArray[hero.id]!["mana"], let manaPerLevel = statsArray[hero.id]!["manaPerLevel"], let manaRegen = statsArray[hero.id]!["manaRegen"], let manaRegenPerLevel = statsArray[hero.id]!["manaRegenPerLevel"] {


                                    let stats = Stats(hp: hp as! Int, hpPerLevel: hpPerLevel as! Int, hpRegen: hpRegen as! Float, hpRegenPerLevel: hpRegenPerLevel as! Float, mana: mana as! Int, manaPerLevel: manaPerLevel as! Int, manaRegen: manaRegen as! Float, manaRegenPerLevel: manaRegenPerLevel as! Float)

                                    hero.stats = stats
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        if let talentsArray = dict[x]["talents"] as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {

                            for y in 0 ..< dict.count {
                                if let allHeroTalents = talentsArray["\(y)"]{
                                    for z in 0 ..< allHeroTalents.count {


                                        if let id = allHeroTalents[z]["id"], let name = allHeroTalents[z]["name"], let descritption = allHeroTalents[z]["description"], var cooldown = allHeroTalents[z]["cooldown"], let prerequisite = allHeroTalents[z]["prerequisite"], let icon = allHeroTalents[z]["icon"] {

                                            print("\(name) and \(cooldown)")

                                            let talent = Talent(id: id as! String, name: name as! String, description: description as! String, cooldown: cooldown as! Int, prerequisite: prerequisite as! String, icon: icon as! String)

                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }






                        }


                        heroes.append(hero)
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch {
            print("Could not serialize")
        }
    }


    }.resume()
```

let me know if more information is needed?

Im very new to coding...started 3 weeks ago so i apologize if the title isn't accurate and my code is inefficient.

*** These are the edits I've made per peoples suggestions

I've taken this out of the if let and made it line item

```
let id = allHeroTalents[z]["id"]
let name = allHeroTalents[z]["name"]
let description = allHeroTalents[z]["description"]
let cooldown = allHeroTalents[z]["cooldown"] ?? 0
let prerequisite = allHeroTalents[z]["prerequisite"] ?? ""
let icon = allHeroTalents[z]["icon"]



let sId = id as! String
let sName = name as! String
let sDescription = description as! String
let iCooldown = cooldown as! Int
let sPrerequisite = prerequisite as! String
let sIcon = icon as! String
let talent = Talent(id: sId, name: sName, description: sDescription, cooldown: iCooldown, prerequisite: sPrerequisite, icon: sIcon)
```

My error is now happening at "let sPrerequisite = prerequisite as! String"

Comment: Show the related JSON. By the way: using backing private variables for read-only properties in Swift is nonsense.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what this means but i'll look into it.

Comment: You can refer my videos at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tBhTZf-4NZo&list=PLT7YNwQNKSPAlf-G12qRzHlw3mwJ0g62s&index=6 if your problem still not solving

Comment: @Apple The problem is that the datatype for 
 let prerequisite = allHeroTalents[z]["prerequisite"] ?? "" 
is not a string.
You have to find a datatype it will succeed at casting it to, and cast it to that before, and than you could take the proper means to cast it to a String after. The code that I shared with you is still not the best way of doing things. It is much safer to avoid force casting when possible by using conditional casting with the ? instead of ! or using if let statements with cast as? Type. I will still force cast sometimes, but you have to be sure of the datas consistency.

Comment: I'm fairly sure of the data type and I don't think that is the issue anymore. What is happening is that for some reason "cooldown" is passing the nil coalescence check (so it never gets the default value set) but is still returning nil when i unwrap it. I used this statement "if allHeroTalents[z]["cooldown"] != nil { print(allHeroTalents[z]["cooldown"]) }" and it will print values sometimes and other times it just prints nil. When I try to cast it after using the nil coalescence it crashes on the first nil it runs into. How is it passing the nil coalescence check and still returning nil?

Answer (score 1):

Use Swift's "Nil Coalescing Operator" ??

```
var cooldown = allHeroTalents[z]["cooldown"] ?? 0
```

Apple documentation at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html

Comment: per your suggestion I tried making the modification you suggested but it didn't work. I'm getting the same error. This is what i implemented   if let id = allHeroTalents[z]["id"], let name = allHeroTalents[z]["name"], let descritption = allHeroTalents[z]["description"], var cooldown = allHeroTalents[z]["cooldown"] ?? 0, let prerequisite = allHeroTalents[z]["prerequisite"], let icon = allHeroTalents[z]["icon"] {

Comment: You probably need to read and understand the documentation rather than just cut and paste and hope, particularly since you describe yourself as "Apple".  ;)  Anyway, assuming the value associated with "cooldown" is an Int, you could try Int(allHeroTalents[z]?["cooldown"]) ?? 0.

Answer (score 0):

This solution assumes nil is acceptable

Apple docs:

> You use optionals in situations where a value may be absent

So change

```
private var _cooldown: Int!
```

to

```
private var _cooldown: Int?
```

And do the same in your init(...) function and your Talent(...) constructor call:

```
cooldown: Int?
cooldown: cooldown as? Int
```

Some [reading material](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID330) for you

Comment: I tried that before posting. I then have to change the let talent = statement so that cooldown: cooldown as! Int and that gives me the same error

Comment: All three changes? What was the result?

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with a problem in code like this

```
let talent = Talent(id: id as! String, name: name as! String, description: description as! String, cooldown: cooldown as! Int, prerequisite: prerequisite as! String, icon: icon as! String)
```

the easiest way to deduce the error is to reduce the code happening in one line. Do this insead:

```
let sId = id as! String
let sName = name as! String
let sDescription = description as! String
let iCooldown = cooldown as! Int
let sPrerequisite = prerequisite as! String
let sIcon = icon as! String
let talent = Talent(id: sId, name: sName, description: sDescription, cooldown: iCooldown, prerequisite: sPrerequisite, icon: sIcon)
```

Now you can see if any of them throw an error directly by the line the error is caused. The other two answers are also good information.

Comment: Using your code helped me identify another issue. "cooldown" need a Nil Coalescing Operator, and so did "prerequisite". The issue I'm having now is that sometimes "prerequisite" doesn't even exist as a key. Using the  if let id = allHeroTalents[z]["id"].... a print indicated that it was only being executed for two of the 10 or so talents. That leads me to think that the other 8 talents don't have a key for prerequisite. However when I break my if let statement into several lines  I get "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" for the line "let sPrerequisite ="